# OpenIddict: Share authentication between ASP.NET Core application and WEB.API Application

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, openiddict, api-authorization

I have an asp.net core web application that using OpenIddict. It works fine and users can login.
Now I want to add web.api hosted on separate subdomain, but because the user is already authenticated I want to somehow share that authentication.
Is it possible? How can I do it? I see in the examples for OpenIddict user have to authenticate again, but I do not want that.

My Setup:

- ASP.NET Core Web App: **app.domain.com**
- OpenIddict server: **login.domain.com**
- Web API .net Core App: **api.domain.com** (that is new requirement)

My web application has views that display data from controllers, I want to add extra javascript logic, and I can have web.api as part of the asp.net core domain: **app.domain.com/api/**
in that case, it works, the authenticated shared between web application and API,
but my goal is to have web.api on a separate subdomain: **api.domain.com**
I know I have to create a Bearer token, but it is not clear how to do it without authenticating the user again. So I want somehow share ASP.NET Core web application authentication to access api.domain.com

Can you please point me in the right direction? Where to start looking?

Comment: I found what was wrong. On the Server I have token encryption enabled, but on the API client, it was not. So whatever token sent to API fails to decrypt it. I guess in that case a more detailed error message would help, but it was too generic to understand why it failing. Once I disabled encryption, it all starts working.

Comment: Do you solved this problem? I have same question.